# When using SQL server 2008 Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Expressand SQL 2008 Sever express edition  and i am getting the following error for any query i execute `Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)` I am new to programming

Comment: Add the query that caused the error or any other code that you use.

Comment: `select * from optname;`

Comment: Look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202414/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-microsoft-sqlserver-smo 
to see if there is an anwer to your question there. Must be a problem with your configuration.

Comment: Hi Tom, I am using both client , sql instance and sever all 2008 version, In the above case , the server has been changed to 2012, but i have not upgraded yet, my client is 2008 and my server is also 2008, thanks for your help,any advise is appreciated