# How to insert data in codename one db using prepared statement?

Tags: arrays, database, codenameone

I am trying to use to insert into the table but got the exception that array index out of bounds ?

Please give me the idea how to do that and where is I am making mistake?
I have tried many conversion but doesn't get succeeded.

Following is the code

```
 Object[]param={ID,name,Fathername,Address,Mob,Gender,Qualification};


 try{
 db=Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("students.db");

 db.execute("insert into clStudent values('?','?','?',?,'?','?','?')", (Object[]) param) ;
```

Comment: you can refer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202414/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-microsoft-sqlserver-smo) the question already like yours!

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the exception from the console?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0                                                                                                this is the exception i am getting when i try to use the getstackTrace () function it gives error that cannot find the symbol method.getstackTrac()         @Shia Almog

Comment: at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.batch(PrepStmt.java:272)
 at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.setNull(PrepStmt.java:403)
 at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.setNull(PrepStmt.java:396)
 at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEDatabase.execute(SEDatabase.java:125)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.DatabaseSQLite.addStudent(DatabaseSQLite.java:99)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.lambda$AddStudentForm$6(MyApplication.java:301)
 at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
 at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:411)
 at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:442)

Comment: Thanks @YngveMoe  it worked

Comment: FYI you should upvote/accept the answer by clicking the checkbox next to it and the up arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should drop the single quotes around the question marks in your query string.