# Index was outside the bounds of the array in SQL Server

Tags: arrays, sql-server-2008-r2, indexoutofboundsexception, bounds

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my PC and while I am running queries it throws the error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

[image: Indexarraybounds_Error]

Before querying the table when I click on table name I see above message.

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this?

Comment: **SHOW US THE CODE** that is causing this error! We cannot see your screen, nor read your mind - you will have to show us something so we can help .....

Comment: A quick Google suggests that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202414/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-microsoft-sqlserver-smo) might be the solution - are you using a different version of SSMS than the version of the SQL instance you are connecting to?

Comment: Alternative,based on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2459027/fix-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-smo-error-message-when-you-connect-to-a-sql-server-code-named-denali-ctp1-database-engine-instance-in-ssms-2008-r2-and-in-ssms-2008), update to at least Cumulative Update 5 of SQL 2008R2.