# SSMS 2008 'An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Using SSMS/SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have the following SQL script that uses two CTEs and a PIVOT statement

```
DECLARE @WEEK_START_SUBTRACTER INT; 
SET @WEEK_START_SUBTRACTER = 34;

-- CTE1 SChedule History (FORECASTS) and Date Dimension
WITH ctevh
AS
(
SELECT 
dd.WeekOfYear - @WEEK_START_SUBTRACTER AS PlanningWeekNo
,sh.FORECAST_CALLS 
,sh.CT_NAME 
,CONVERT(varchar(10),sh.SCHED_DATE,120) AS SCHED_DATE

FROM  dbo.DateDimension dd 
INNER JOIN Planning.ScheduleHistory sh 
ON dd.Date = sh.EXTRACT_DATE 

)
--CTE 2 VirtualQueues (ACTUALS) and Business Areas
, ctevq
AS
(
SELECT vq.StartDate
,ba.IEXDescription
,SUM(vq.Offered) AS Offered
FROM  Planning.VirtualQueues vq 
INNER JOIN
Planning.BusinessAreas ba 
ON vq.VirtualQueue = ba.VirtualQueue

GROUP BY ba.IEXDescription, vq.StartDate

HAVING ba.IEXDescription = 'Personal'
OR
ba.IEXDescription = 'Corporate'
OR
ba.IEXDescription = 'Company'
)

-- Join the two CTEs
SELECT  *
FROM ctevh
LEFT OUTER JOIN ctevq
ON ctevh.CT_NAME = ctevq.IEXDescription
AND
ctevh.SCHED_DATE = ctevq.StartDate

PIVOT (
MAX(ctevh.FORECAST_CALLS)
FOR PlanningWeekNo in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) AS pvt
```

I get the following error which I think is being caused by the PIVOT part:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

If I replace CTE2 'ctevq' with an actual (exact) VIEW then the script runs fine.

I've searched online and the overall solution seems to be to upgrade your SSMS/SQL Server. Neither of which is an option

Comment: How about a newer version of SSMS? Installing that should do you no harm but as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202414/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-microsoft-sqlserver-smo) it can help.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no control over what SSMS is installed. I actually do have SSMS 2016 installed but could never connect to any of our SQL Servers just stuck with 2008 R2