# Array Out of Index in SQL Server

Tags: ssms, erd

While trying to generate the diagram for a database (in SQL Server 2017), I am getting an error

> Array out of Index

When I restart the application, it works fine for some time, and after few minutes, when I try to add a new table to the Diagram, it shows that same error again.

Is there any solution to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's a bug with SSMS (v17.4 in my case).

Others have reported similar issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44914581/4768230.

Alternatively, others have suggested making sure you have schema declared for all your tables can possibly help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660066/4768230 (I haven't tried this though).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative answer that applies to a very specific situation.

The above answer will most likely solve your problem.  However if you run SSMS as a different user than you are logged into Windows as you may get this error.

The workarounds are to either

- Use your normal Windows to connect to the SQL Server (which may not be allowed depending on your situation)
- User Remote Desktop to connect to a machine with your SQL Account.

Tested with:

- Windows 7 64bit
- SSMS 17.7

This situation might be related to the computer not being enabled to use Kerberos Double-Hop active directory but this statement is complete conjecture.